# How can I persistently set the interrupt character in a particular tty?

Tags: linux, shell, redhat, tty

I was reading [this article](http://linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) and was able to set the terminal interrupt character to `o` using `stty intr o`.

However, after the first time I used `o`, the interrupt character would get reset to `^C` again.

**How can I persist an `intr` setting on a given `tty`?**

**Update** with more machine information.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ uname -a
Linux <hostname_foobar> 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:33:01 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update**: This appears to only happen if I access to machine above over SSH. I have tested both with key-based login and with password-based login and it reproduces across both cases.

Comment: this could be version specific bug. consider adding output from `bash --version` (if that is your shell) and `uname`. I'd recommend adding at tag for `linux` or `unix` as appropriate, to get more eyes on this question. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, Updated and retagged. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: hmm... v `2.6...` sounds really old. What do you get from running `lsb_release -a`? Also, if you have an alternate computer, do you get the same issue there? (I'm not sure why this Q got a downvote, but maybe the downvoter thinks this is more appropriate to http://unix.stackexchange.com OR http://askubuntu.com. You can flag the question for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved to one of those if you want). I'm going to try this on my Ubuntu. Good luck.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. once I assign `stty intr o`, when I do `stty -a`, I can see that `intr = o`, and if I type `o` (only), on the cmd line, I get a new cmd-line (as if I had typed the 'Enter' key. I can revert to `intr = ^C` by typing `stty sane`. If you are loading a large enviroment of functions for a project, also best to confirm that your problem exists in a very simple environment. Also, not clear why you want to do this. I understand hiding 'Ctrl-C' behavior, but not with 'o' char ;-). Finally, the old version seems the most likely problem. Test on a new version. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, Just observed that this only happens over ssh.

Comment: Consider editing your question to the minimal number of steps required to replicate the problem. Include if you're using ssh passwords, or if you've created a password-less environment. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Question has been updated. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Making it persistent will be somewhat distro specific. The general configuration is spread between `/usr/share/terminfo/` and `/usr/share/misc/termcap` (with softlinks in `/etc`) A good starting place would be taking a look at `man 5 terminfo` to see whether a terminal parameter provides the hook or whether you will need to update your termcap file with the keydef.

Comment: @merlin2011 : OK, you're latest update is something I can't test. Need specific code to execute that always creates the problem for you (and for "us"). Most importantly, the place to start is to prove this happens in anyone's environment, and that is not something specific to your configuration. Given 3 machines, do you get the same problem when connecting from A->B, B->C, A->C, C->A, C->B, B->A (for example). Have you hidden all of your `.profile, .bashrc` and similar? Oh yeah, add OS version for remote machine, and if different, output from `ssh --version` from all machines. Good luck.